# Mobile geolocation into subway

Tags: mobile, geolocation

i would like to create a tracking mobile app that work with google maps.
how can i track a mobile phone when it is under the ground (es subway) or it is inside a building (es shopping center) ?
is there a google API that track the position of the phone ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you question seems very broad. getting access to location for a mobile it depends on platform or the device you are working on and its not about the google API. 
google API allows you to do some cool stuff with the location you get from the device or technically from the OS on the device.

device depends on whether its android or iOS or some other OS. they have different rules and level of permissions. for example on iOS devices you have limitation on when you can get access to user's location when you app is not active.

so my suggestion is to narrow down your question and let us know what exactly you want to know about geolocation.

Answer (score 0):

I wolud like to use react native or flutter to create a cross-platform app for android e iOS.
i need a function that when press a button the gps starts tracking my movements and write its on the maps (like runtastic or the app that write on the map the paths when you run or walk).
The problem is, how can i track when there isn't GPS, like in the subway ?